# Where is the NuGet package for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime?

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, azure-sdk-.net, azure-service-runtime

We had previously been referring to our Windows Azure libraries via the SDK and I noticed that they have [NuGet packages for them now](http://nuget.org/packages?q=windowsazureofficial).  This is obviously way better, so I'm swapping out all of those references for the NuGet packages.

However, I can't find a NuGet package for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll that contains classes such as [RoleEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.aspx), etc.

Are we supposed to be referencing this dll from the SDK installation and not a nuget package?  That seems extremely odd.  Am I just not seeing the package for this assembly?

I've now installed all of the "windowsazureofficial" tagged packages (just temporarily) and none of them seem to have the correct reference!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The latest [Windows Azure SDK is 1.7](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/) so If you need updated Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime you would have to manually install the SDK in your machine and add those references to your role.

Comment: Right, and I've done that.  It just seems odd that they would include certain parts of the 1.6 and 1.7 SDK as NuGet Packages, but not all of the parts.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of Nuget packages? Nuget is supposed to make it easy to integrate with external libraries - why do I have to install an SDK when Nuget can already manage the proper dependencies? This needs to be fixed - why does the community need to manage the **Unofficial Service Runtime**?

Comment: @SliverNinja, the SDK contains the emulator and other stuff as well, which in turn depends on the assemblies like `MS.WA.ServiceRuntime`. Nobody needs the Unofficial Service Runtime.

Comment: @bzlm - You make the assumption that everyone uses the emulator - not always the case. We rarely emulate since we already have a predefined pattern for integrating the **Service Runtime**. Nuget makes managing different versions much simpler since every developer likely has a different version depending on how often they update. It would be great if the **Service Runtime** could be managed like the [**Service Bus**](http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus). Also as your projects age - it may not get updated depending on the deployment cycle. This can cause maintenance issues.

Comment: @SliverNinja, I'm currently trying to upgrade a SDK1.8 .NET4 solution to SDK2.0 .NET4.5, and it's hell on earth. So I agree with you that it would be 1000 times better if *everything* was managed via packages. I'm just saying that since the emulator is tightly coupled with the runtime, I can understand why some assemblies are in the SDK folder and some are managed via packages. I don't think it's helpful for developers though. Adding references to the SDK folder on disk feels wrong. I was also pointing out that nobody needs the unofficial service runtime.

Comment: Things have changed and the correct answer should now be David's answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37393352/2575839

Answer (score 22):

[image: How to add Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime]

For anyone still battling, make sure you look under Assemblies > Extensions ;) This has now got me twice within 3 months!

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem.

**Option 1)**

I added a `dll` libray in my Google Drive Storage: [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudDrive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5-vV6C0Mbm4fi16bTcxNmhzdEZMYWhTZDVpbFNKdWdMRXVIbC0zelk4U25iS2NWbXM1VVU&usp=sharing)

In this case you should download and create a "static" link.

**Option 2)**

and I found a NuGet Package:

[Azure SDK 2.2 DLLs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureSDK2.2DLLs/)

`PM> Install-Package AzureSDK2.2DLLs`

If you need more information, please contact me.

Comment: Option 2 worked like a treat! This should be now the correct answer.

Comment: option 2 is not an official microsoft package you should use the offical binaries

Comment: @Dizzle package is very old and removed from official binaries but have old projects which need this dependency.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the particular version of the Azure SDK which you want to build with.

Actually you only need to install certain parts of it including the reference libraries(there are multiple parts of the SDK you can download separately) - and it depends which assemblies you are looking for.

e.g. for 2.2 or 2.3 SDK and **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime** or **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics** assemblies, you need the 'WindowsAzureAuthoringTools' MSI installer - not the 'WindowsAzureLibsForNet-x64' MSI, which installs some of the other reference libraries.

Comment: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime is currently in MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics is currently in MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet

Both available from Azure SDK for .NET here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/

(Azure SDK version at time of posting is 2.7)

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be one at this time, but I found this:  [AnglicanGeek's Unofficial Windows Azure Service Runtime 1.6](http://nuget.org/packages/AnglicanGeek.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime)

Comment: I just found that, wow, really surprising that they dont support this.  I guess I'll just create a nuget package for it on our internal nuget server and use that until they get around to making one

Answer (score 2):

It's now a regular package on NuGet:

`Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.SDK`

Comment: it is unofficial

Answer (score 1):

Its likely that they don't want to distribute the core parts of the SDK so you still have a requirement to install the actual SDK.  I messaged (via nuget) the owners of the "windowsazureofficial" nuget packages and asked for feedback and I'll update this if I hear back.

As for upgrading, first get the [sdk](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/) and then follow the upgrade instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj131257).  The references will automatically be updated and it will convert local references to nuget package references as well, when it can.

Comment: For others reference, you can find `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll` in the path `Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\<sdk_version>\bin\runtimes\base`.

Comment: @SliverNinja-MSFT Any chance you could make this comment an answer, because it's easy to go over, but actually solved my problem?

Comment: @Derptastic - added per request to make more discoverable.

Answer (score 1):

List with all Azure Packages: [Azure SDK for .NET](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/)

> Note: Before downloading the SDK files, review the installation steps
>   to understand the process and dependencies involved in installing the
>   SDK. For SDK 1.7 and later releases, use the installation steps
>   included with the Manual Installers links below. For SDK 1.6 and
>   earlier, follow the installation steps listed later on this page.

Answer (score 1):

You can find `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll` located in the path:

```
Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\<sdk_version>\bin\runtimes\base
```